# Drop position of image not accurate

Tags: jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop, position

I have a workspace with its `width: 800px` and `height: 450px`. Image not get drop in correct position inside the workspace. In the left side the position x and y will display the position of the image where dropped. The `left(x)` and `top(y)` corner of workspace is `0`. After image gets dropped into workspace, the image gets workspace x and y position from `0`.

I used left and top adjustment code, but it not works perfect. Below is the code used to adjust the position while drop the image.

```
leftAdjust = Math.abs(obj.position().left) - Math.abs($(window).width()-(workspace.offset().left + workspace.outerWidth()));

topAdjust = obj.position().top - workspace.offset().top;
```

Code in [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/8zp9kfpj/2/)..

This is the correctly working example [link](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/8zp9kfpj/3/) ... Which works correctly for left to right side image drag. But i need to drag image from right to left side.

Run the given link in Jsfiddle with large size as much as possible..

Comment: What's the correct position exactly?

Comment: @8odoros.. When i drop image in workspace at  top:0 and left:0, then i need to get the result as x: 0 and y: 0.

Comment: @8odoros.. I will give another link for clear understanding...

Comment: @8odoros.. This is the correctly working example [link](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/8zp9kfpj/3/) ... Which works correctly for left side image drag. But i need to drag image from right side..